# IntentBuilder not recognized in Android Studio (Google PlacePicker)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, gmsplacepicker

I'm trying to create a PlacePicker for my Google Maps Application, and found a nice guide to do this. The guide isen't terribly outdated, so i didn't expect it to use any deprecated features. As it turns out, it does, and i'm kinda confused as to how to deal with this issue, me still being new to Android Development.

I've never used an IntentBuilder before, so i'm not sure if it's even used properly. It seems as if Android merely doesn't know what it is at all, as the suggested solution is making it a class.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.ChildEventListener;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ServerValue;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class PlacePicker extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, ChildEventListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LatLngBounds.Builder mBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
private static final int REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER = 1;
public static final int REQUEST_ID_ACCESS_COURSE_FINE_LOCATION = 100;

private static final String FIREBASE_URL = "MYURL";
private static final String FIREBASE_ROOT_NODE = "checkouts";

private Firebase mFirebase;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_picker);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // Set up the API client for Places API
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkout_button);
    button.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGlobalLayout() {
                    mMap.setPadding(0, button.getHeight(), 0, 0);
                }
            }
    );

    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
    mFirebase = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
    mFirebase.child(FIREBASE_ROOT_NODE).addChildEventListener(this);


}

public void checkOut(View view) {
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please install Google Play Services!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void addPointToViewPort(LatLng newPoint) {
    mBounds.include(newPoint);
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mBounds.build(),
            findViewById(R.id.checkout_button).getHeight()));
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PLACE_PICKER) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data, this);

            Map<String, Object> checkoutData = new HashMap<>();
            checkoutData.put("time", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

            mFirebase.child(FIREBASE_ROOT_NODE).child(place.getId()).setValue(checkoutData);

        } else if (resultCode == PlacePicker.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Places API failure! Check the API is enabled for your key",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

@Override
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    String placeId = dataSnapshot.getKey();
    if (placeId != null) {
        Places.GeoDataApi
                .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                                           LatLng location = places.get(0).getLatLng();
                                           addPointToViewPort(location);
                                           mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location));
                                           places.release();
                                       }
                                   }
                );
    }
}
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        int accessCoarsePermission
                = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        int accessFinePermission
                = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);


        if (accessCoarsePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                || accessFinePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // The Permissions to ask user.
            String[] permissions = new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};
            // Show a dialog asking the user to allow the above permissions.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions,
                    REQUEST_ID_ACCESS_COURSE_FINE_LOCATION);

            return;
        }
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            LatLng ll = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            addPointToViewPort(ll);
            // we only want to grab the location once, to allow the user to pan and zoom freely.
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
        }
    });
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera

}
```

Also getPlace and RESULT_ERROR is red aswell, and unrecognized by Android Studio here.

I am not sure if i'm allowed to post the link to the guide in question, so i'll only post if asked.

I am still pretty new to Android Studio, so all help is much appreciated!

Comment: have you added the import? `import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;`

Comment: @antonio that particular import is not recoqnized either, but i have added all normal places import. I have editted my answer with imports.

Comment: Depending on the Google Play services version that you are you using, you might need to make the changes in your app for the [new permissions model](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html). 

As stated in [Place Picker permissions](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker#permissions), provided you're using version 8.1 or later of Google Play services, you can configure your app to target the Android 6.0 Marshmallow SDK and use the new permissions model.

Comment: going back to the old permission model worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

please add this to your dependencies in your app.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
```

Comment: i already have 9.4.0 in dependencies, should i use 9.2.0? Was IntentBuilder deprecated?

Comment: you need to add the places library since 9.2.0
and change this if you have it in your code
import com.google.android.gms.location.places;
to

import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;

Comment: tried to go from 9.4.0 places library to 9.2.0 places library, and i'm still getting the same error.